# Extract X% of random words from a string

Tags: r

I have a column with text; where I would like to extract 20% of random words from each cell.

Example data:

```
text <- c("five1 five2 five3 five4 five5", "ten1 ten2 ten3 ten4 ten5 ten6 ten7 ten8 ten9 ten10", "fifteen1 fifteen2 fifteen3 fifteen4 fifteen5 fifteen6 fifteen7 fifteen8 fifteen9 fifteen10 fifteen11 fifteen12 fifteen13 fifteen14 fifteen15")
id <- c(1, 2, 3)
df <- data.frame(text, id)
```

This is an example of how the end result could look:

```
 df$text_20_random_percent <- c("five4", "ten7 ten2", "fifteen2 fifteen12 fifteen3")
```

I have tried using the `sample()` function without success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to split the string into substring using `strsplit`, get the `sample` of the `split` words by specifying the `size` as the X% of `length` and `paste` it together

```
sapply(strsplit(as.character(df$text), " "), 
        function(x) paste(sample(x, 0.2 * length(x)), collapse=' '))
```